# no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError). Wraith BBC-News project

Tags: ruby

I have file which i want to run:

When i write:

```
wraith capture configs/config.yaml
```

I've got the next:

```
/Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/wraith.rb:172:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/wraith.rb:172:in `verbose'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/wraith.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/validate.rb:10:in `new'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/validate.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/cli.rb:132:in `new'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/cli.rb:132:in `block in capture'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/cli.rb:28:in `within_acceptable_limits'
    from /Users/lvlmd/wraith/lib/wraith/cli.rb:131:in `capture'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/wraith-3.1.2/bin/wraith:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/wraith:23:in `load'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/wraith:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/lvlmd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

How to fix that? How to start process? i cant understand the probleb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved.

Edited .bash_profile
added

```
export PATH=/Users/User_Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wraith:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your configuration is wrong, check out the source https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith/blob/master/lib/wraith/wraith.rb#L172

Comment: do you mean configuration inside this file "configs/config.yaml?

Comment: yes, if you're missing something in there or you put something in the wrong type you'll see errors like this. lookup in the source what line you errored on for an idea on what you inputed incorrectly